# WPF Touch - Choosing Manipulation Container based on number of manipulators

Tags: c#, wpf, touch

I have a WPF Touch app (MS Surface, VS 2017, .NET 4.7) that shows a number of simple shapes (lines, rects, circles) above an image, all on on a canvas.  I'm having a trouble with selecting my ManipulationContainer for touch.

Roughly what I have is this:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="MyViewer"  
              ManipulationStarting="Viewer_ManipulationStarting">
    <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas">
        <Image x:Name="MyImage" Source={Binding MyImageSource}"/>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="MyShapes" ItemsSource="{Binding MyShapes}"/>
    </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I want let my user do two different things with touch.

1. With one finger they can draw new shapes (relative to the canvas)
2. With two fingers they can zoom the entire canvas (relative to the scrollviewer)

So if the user is drawing a new shape, then ManipulationContainer must be "MyCanvas".  But if the user is zooming the whole scene,  then the ManipulationContainer must be "MyViewer" (because in that case I'm changing the LayoutTransform of the whole canvas).

So I need (it would seem) to select from one of two different manipulation containers depending on which of these operations is happening.  But I can't seem to figure out how.  Below is what I have (which doesn't work) where I choose the container. in the ManipulationStarting handler.

```
private void Scene_ManipulationStarting(object sender, ManipulationStartingEventArgs e)
{
    // If zooming, container is the parent viewer.  Otherwise it's
    // drawing a shape relative to the canvas.  

    if (e.Manipulators.Count() >= 2)
        e.ManipulationContainer = MyViewer;  // Zooming whole canvas
    else
        e.ManipulationContainer = MyCanvas;  // Drawing on canvas


    e.Handled               = true;
}
```

As you likely guessed, when I first get this, I always get just  one manipulator; The user is extremely unlikely to have his very first touch be with two fingers exactly simultaneously.  So my code always thinks I'm drawing a shape.

It's only later on, in the ManipulationDelta that I start getting more than one manipulator.  But it's too late then to choose a container.  It's already been chosen.  And if I check the number of manipulators then, my coordinates, delta, and origin are all relative to the very thing I'm trying to move.  It makes the zooming jump all over the place.

I don't know what to do about this.  I have to let my user zoom at any time so I do not have the option of forcing them to choose a "zoom tool".

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I don't know what it is and I'd like to avoid blind alleys.  Any suggestions?